# Subsetting with harmony

Tags: r, seurat, single-cell, batch-effects

Currently merged two Seurat objects together and then ran Harmony for batch correction. Now I want to subset out a cell type of interest do I re run harmony or just do the standard PCA?

```
scData <- scData %>% 
    RunUMAP(reduction = "harmony", dims = 1:14) %>% 
    FindNeighbors(reduction = "harmony", dims = 1:14) %>% 
    FindClusters(resolution = 0.2) %>% 
    identity()
```

```
numPC = 14
scData <- FindNeighbors(scData, dims = 1:numPC)
scData <- FindClusters(scData, resolution = 0.2, dims = 1:numPC)
scData <- RunUMAP(scData, dims = 1:numPC)
```

Both options give me different results. Not sure what the correct way to it is.

---

From the Broad Institute website:
https://portals.broadinstitute.org/harmony/

"Harmony is a general-purpose R package with an efficient algorithm for integrating multiple data sets. It is especially useful for large single-cell datasets such as single-cell RNA-seq."